# UIWebView overriding touch events in my UITableViewCell subclass

Tags: ios, uiview, uitableview

I have a UIWebView in a UIView subclass stored in a UITableViewCell subclass. I've noticed that I lose touch events in my view controller. How can I get around this?

I've tried

```
- (BOOL) canResignFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}
```

in my custom UIView. I want the UIWebView to receive touch input when the one div is selected. I thought about making the div 100% high but that causes other problems. I was thinking of allowing the UIView subclass to resign first responder status so that tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath would be called but doesn't seem to work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the gesture recognizer delegate method `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:`? You can read about it here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html